# Find possible minimal polynomial for $L^3 + 2L^2 + L + 3 \cdot I_v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:
$L: V \rightarrow V ; L^2 + I_v = 0$

Find:
possibilities for the minimal polynom of $L^3+2L^2+L+3\cdot I_v$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted using any of the given information to simplify $L^3+2L^2+L+3I_v$?

Comment: I have thought about it this way but i'm not sure if I am headed the right way: L^2 = -I_v so, the given polynomial can be simplified to L^3+L = -I_v or (-L-3*I_v) * L = I_v. I still don't see how to find minimal poly with this new info.

Comment: Using $L^2=-I_v$, you should be able to rewrite the entire polynomial as degree 1. $L^3=L\cdot L^2$, right?

Answer (score 1):

$x - 1$.  The one and only minimal polynomial of $L^3 + 2L^2 + L + 3I_V \;$ when $L^2 + I_V = 0$ is $x - 1$.

Observe that

$x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 3 = (x + 2)(x^2 + 1) + 1, \tag{1}$

which in turn implies, since $L^2 + I_V = 0$,

$L^3 + 2L^2 + L + 3I_V = (L + 2I_V)(L^2 + I_V) + I_V = I_V; \tag{2}$

the one and only minimal polynomial of $I_V$ is $x - 1$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***